# Systemd service not running

Tags: bash, debian, systemd, raspberry-pi, rclone

I modified [this script](https://blog.rymcg.tech/blog/linux/rclone_sync/#:%7E:text=RClone%20is%20an%20excellent%2C%20open,lot%20of%20different%20service%20backends.) to help me continuously sync a folder to a remote using rclone. The code for said script is posted below. My issue is that on first run, it seemed to be syncing properly, only I was syncing the wrong folder. So I tried killing the process and running it again, only then it stopped syncing. Eventually I would delete my entire .config folder (where the service file was being held), create a new rclone remote using `rclone config`, and reboot my system. Now it seems that it only syncs when the script is first run, and never again after that. It seems like the systemd service is just not running  for whatever reason, and I can't figure out why. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
## One-way, immediate, continuous, recursive, directory synchronization
##  to a remote Rclone URL. ( S3, SFTP, FTP, WebDAV, Dropbox, etc. )
## Optional desktop notifications on sync events or errors.
## Useful only for syncing a SMALL number of files (< 8192).
##  (See note in `man inotifywait` under `--recursive` about raising this limit.)
## Think use-case: Synchronize Traefik TLS certificates file (acme.json)
## Think use-case: Synchronize Keepass (.kdbx) database file immediately on save.
## Think use-case: Live edit source code and push to remote server

## This is NOT a backup tool! 
## It will not help you if you delete your files or if they become corrupted.

## Setup: Install `rclone` from package manager.
## Run: `rclone config` to setup the remote, including the full remote
##   subdirectory path to sync to.
## MAKE SURE that the remote (sub)directory is EMPTY
##   or else ALL CONTENTS WILL BE DELETED by rclone when it syncs.
## If unsure, add `--dry-run` to the RCLONE_CMD variable below, 
##   to simulate what would be copied/deleted. 
## Copy this script any place, and make it executable: `chown +x sync.sh`
## Edit all the variables below, before running the script.
## Run: `./sync.sh systemd_setup` to create and enable systemd service.
## Run: `journalctl --user --unit rclone_sync.${RCLONE_REMOTE}` to view the logs.

## Edit the variables below, according to your own environment:

# RCLONE_SYNC_PATH: The path to COPY FROM (files are not synced TO here):
RCLONE_SYNC_PATH="/home/user/dav-sync"

# RCLONE_REMOTE: The rclone remote name to synchronize with.
# Identical to one of the remote names listed via `rclone listremotes`.
# Make sure to include the final `:` in the remote name, which
#   indicates to sync/delete from the same (sub)directory as defined in the URL.
# (ALL CONTENTS of the remote are continuously DELETED
#  and replaced with the contents from RCLONE_SYNC_PATH)
RCLONE_REMOTE="my-webdav-remote:"

# RCLONE_CMD: The sync command and arguments:
RCLONE_CMD="rclone -v sync ${RCLONE_SYNC_PATH} ${RCLONE_REMOTE}"

# WATCH_EVENTS: The file events that inotifywait should watch for:
WATCH_EVENTS="modify,delete,create,move"

# SYNC_DELAY: Wait this many seconds after an event, before synchronizing:
SYNC_DELAY=5

# SYNC_INTERVAL: Wait this many seconds between forced synchronizations:
SYNC_INTERVAL=3600

# NOTIFY_ENABLE: Enable Desktop notifications
NOTIFY_ENABLE=true

# SYNC_SCRIPT: dynamic reference to the current script path
SYNC_SCRIPT=$(realpath $0)

notify() {
    MESSAGE=$1
    if test ${NOTIFY_ENABLE} = "true"; then
        notify-send "rclone ${RCLONE_REMOTE}" "${MESSAGE}"
    fi
}

rclone_sync() {
    set -x
    # Do initial sync immediately:
    notify "Startup"
    ${RCLONE_CMD}
    # Watch for file events and do continuous immediate syncing
    # and regular interval syncing:
    while [[ true ]] ; do
    inotifywait --recursive --timeout ${SYNC_INTERVAL} -e ${WATCH_EVENTS} \
            ${RCLONE_SYNC_PATH} 2>/dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        # File change detected, sync the files after waiting a few seconds:
        sleep ${SYNC_DELAY} && ${RCLONE_CMD} && \
        notify "Synchronized new file changes"
    elif [ $? -eq 1 ]; then
        # inotify error occured
        notify "inotifywait error exit code 1"
        sleep 10
    elif [ $? -eq 2 ]; then
        # Do the sync now even though no changes were detected:
        ${RCLONE_CMD}
    fi
    done
}

systemd_setup() {
    set -x
    if loginctl show-user ${USER} | grep "Linger=no"; then
        echo "User account does not allow systemd Linger."
        echo "To enable lingering, run as root: loginctl enable-linger $USER"
        echo "Then try running this command again."
        exit 1
    fi
    mkdir -p ${HOME}/.config/systemd/user
    SERVICE_FILE=${HOME}/.config/systemd/user/rclone_sync.${RCLONE_REMOTE}.service
    if test -f ${SERVICE_FILE}; then
        echo "Unit file already exists: ${SERVICE_FILE} - Not overwriting."
    else
        cat <<EOF > ${SERVICE_FILE}
[Unit]
Description=rclone_sync ${RCLONE_REMOTE}

[Service]
ExecStart=${SYNC_SCRIPT}

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
EOF
    fi
    systemctl --user daemon-reload
    systemctl --user enable --now rclone_sync.${RCLONE_REMOTE}
    systemctl --user status rclone_sync.${RCLONE_REMOTE}
    echo "You can watch the logs with this command:"
    echo "   journalctl --user --unit rclone_sync.${RCLONE_REMOTE}"
}

if test $# = 0; then
    rclone_sync
else
    CMD=$1; shift;
    ${CMD} $@
fi
```

Comment: The `$PATH` (and `$PWD` and other environment variables) differ between a `systemd` service and your desktop environment. Try using full paths for each command.

Comment: @waltinator Where in that script is the `$PATH` environment variable used? Could you be more specific with what you want me to replace?

Comment: @BobSmith : `PATH` is used every time you issue a command without specifying the fill path. So, if you have `mkdir` in your script, the shell will look in the directories listed in the `PATH` to find the program that corresponds to it. Alternatively, you may specify the full path name yourself, like `/usr/bin/kdir`.